# mysql c api mysql_fetch_row() copy fields

Tags: mysql, sql, c

Once the result is returned from mysql_fetch_row() how can the fields from the row be copied separately. My data will only be 1 row

Similar to Steve's suggestion is working.

```
mysql_query(conn, querystring);
  result = mysql_store_result(conn);
  num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);


  if (nums_row == 0){
    printf("%s\n", "No data");
  } else {

    printf("%s\n", "Got data");
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    printf("%s\n", row[0]);
    printf("%s\n", row[1]);
  }
```

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Post some sample code and explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: the C api fetch returns an array, so you'd copy the data the same way you copy anything from an array in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you get back is an array:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$field0 = $row[0];
$field1 = $row[1];
...
```

or you can use list to assign variables:

```
list($field0, $field1, ...) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

or you can use an associative array:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$field0 = $row["field0"];
```

Comment: is this php? I am looking to do it in C

Comment: You didn't post any code - so how was I to know you wanted to do it in C? And therefore it's not fair to mark me down.